# Reverse percentage reduction formula

Tags: percentages

Consider i need to reduce a value by percentage

```
100 - 10% = x
100 - (100 * 10 / 100) = 90
```

So we know `x` is `90`
Now how do i reverse it? consider this question:

```
x - 10% = 90
```

How i can find `x`?
What will be the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are throwing around symbols without rigor.

The "equation"
$$100-10\%=x$$

is meaningless. Specifically, the "$-10\%$" doesn't make sense. You aren't subtracting ten percent, you are subtracting ten percent *of something* (even though people usually say it that way).

Your question is "If I reduce a number by $10\%$ and the result it $90$, what was the original number?". So be more rigorous in using mathematical notation to represent the facts:

$$x - \tfrac{10}{100}x = 90$$
Solve for $x$:
$$\tfrac{100}{100}x - \tfrac{10}{100}x = 90$$
$$\left(\tfrac{100}{100} - \tfrac{10}{100}\right)x = 90$$
$$\left(\tfrac{90}{100}\right)x = 90$$
$$\left(\tfrac{100}{90}\right)\left(\tfrac{90}{100}\right)x = \left(\tfrac{100}{90}\right)90$$
$$x = 100$$

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation you would do:$$x-10\%=90$$$$x-x*\frac{10}{100}=90$$$$x\left(1-\frac{10}{100}\right)=90$$$$x*\frac{90}{100}=90$$$$\therefore x=100$$